# django-graphql-jwt JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE not working

Tags: django, cookies, jwt, apollo-client, graphene-python

I'm using [Django GraphQL JWT Library](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/index.html) and [Django GraphQL Auth](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I keep getting this error
[google chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7doy.png)

With this react code (trimmed for relevancy) on both http://localhost:3000/ and https://localhost:3000/

```
    const [login] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password
        },
        onCompleted: ({ tokenAuth }) => {
            if (tokenAuth.success) {
                setToken(tokenAuth.token);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now when I run this mutation from the graphiql page it works and I end up with a JWT cookie but not on the react site

```
mutation {
  tokenAuth(
    email:"********"
    password:"*********"
  ){
    token
    refreshToken
    success
    errors
  }
}
```

This doesn't work

```
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE": 'None',
    "JWT_ALLOW_ARGUMENT": True
}
```

Adding these didn't work

```
    "CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE": True,
    "SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE": True,
    "CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE": 'None',
    "SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE": 'None',
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
```

Adding these to django settings also didn't work

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

I've been stuck on this for about 3 days now and am about ready to throw myself in a river and go build tables. Please help.

Comment: I don't know if it's related but there's a github thread for this https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/issues/216 . Can you update your django-graphql-jwt version?

Comment: @JechChua My god turns out Django GraphQL Auth doesn't support GraphQL JWT Library v3.1 and I had to uninstall and then update. Thank you so much I might've been stuck for another few days. I'm a bit new to stackoverflow so I'm not entirely sure how this works. Do you now put in an answer and I mark that as completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the `JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE` setting was added for django-graphql-jwt on version `v0.3.2`. You can check the releases here [releases](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/releases). While the current django-graphql-auth package relies on django-graphql-jwt `v0.3.0`. Updating your requirements will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

so the issue is you are using
`"JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE": 'None'`
which only works if
`"JWT_COOKIE_SECURE": True`

and JWT_COOKIE_SECURE means the cookie will only be sent over HTTPS connection and this won't work with HTTP connection.

considering you have HTTP and the backend is using the same domain as frontend then all you need to add is
`"JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE": 'Lax'`
`"JWT_COOKIE_SECURE": False`

cookies are default into `“SameSite=Lax”` which means cookies are only set when the domain in the URL of the browser matches the domain of the cookie